# storing the result of a dictionary to the database using Python (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, database, postgresql, dictionary, psycopg2

i want to insert the result from the below dictionary to the database ( i'm using PostgreSQL) :

```
companies_list = dict(zip(code, short_name))
```

the result for this dictionary after running the code and printing will show the following ( as an example ):

```
companies_list = { '00001': 'A', '00002': 'B', '0010': 'Z'}
```

so when i tried to insert the dictionary above to the database ( code ) below :

```
con = None
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'testdb' user='user'")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE companies_info(code TEXT PRIMARY KEY, short_name TEXT)")


query = "INSERT INTO companies_info ( code, short_name) VALUES ( %(code)s, %(short_name)s)"
cur.executemany(query, companies_list)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

i get the following:

```
cur.executemany(query, companies_list)
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

anyone can fix his error ?

Comment: You don't need to do this, postgres supports json now. If you're on the latest postgres... http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation

Comment: i just started with postgresql and struggling with it ,, i tried the following : 'curs.execute("insert into companies_info (jsondata) values (%s)",
    [Json(companies_list)])'   .... and it gave ne the fllowing error :      'NameError: global name 'Json' is not defined'   bear with I'm just starting with databases. by self learning.

Comment: I think you get it from here `from psycopg.extras import Json` -- but i cant test it.. im not sure. Someone here correct me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
code = ['00001', '00002', '0010']
short_name = ['A', 'B', 'Z']
companies_list = [tuple((t,)) for t in zip(code, short_name)]
query = "insert into companies_info (code, short_name) values %s"
cursor.executemany(query, companies_list)
```

Comment: I tired it and got the fllowing error :
    'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

i don't know if this related or not but ( code, short_name) is the result of scraping a website, following code :
    ' short_name = tree.xpath('//table[@class = "Table3"]//td[3]/text()')
      code  = tree.xpath('//table[@class = "Table3"]//td[1]/text()')'

Comment: @T.M Updated and tested

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm , but can you explain this line for me so in understand it very well..  'tuple((t,)) for t in zip(code, short_name)]'.. i'm always interested in how not what's the solution. appreciate it.